# SharePoint Online : search configuration

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, pnp-powershell

I've been trying to do do some cleanup in my search config as I made many tests on my tenant and I can't find a way to :

- delete a ResultSource (added via searchadmin/EditResultSource.aspx)
- cleanup crappy crawled properties that are duplicates after many tests.

Anyone got a clue on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Result sources** can be deleted manually via UI, in the browser. I am not aware of an API endpoint available to manage these in SharePoint Online.

**Crawled properties** in SharePoint Online cannot be created or deleted. Not manually, not via code. Crawled properties are added automatically, without our control. I also don't think they will ever be deleted.

By the way, this is why in SharePoint Online, whenever I had to develop anything related to the search schema, I had to create an entire new Dev tenant. This was even more important whenever you had to do search-related development for *multiple* clients. Once search schema gets polluted, there is no way to reset it to the original clean state.

Comment: Ohhh.... I'm so sorry I haven't seen the tiny array for context menu !  Thanks you so much for helping.  And, no worries, my tests had been done in a dev tenant ! :D  Problem is that I've been working on an Intranet conversion from SP2010 and there's a lot of junk (over the years) that had been converted when importing document librairies with metadata.

Comment: I was trying to be "as clean as possible" after my final conversion steps.  Understanding crawled / managed properties and how the are auto created is quite hard.